# Adding and using Multiple Connectionstrings in .net core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

I am new to .Net Core - I need to add 2 connectionstrings (One for test db and one for live db), and want to connect to both - i.e. connect to live db and transfer data over to test db. Below is my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=[DB];User Id=[Username];Password=[Password];",
    "MarkingManagerLIVEConnection": "Server=[IP];Database=[DB];User Id=[Username];Password=[Password]"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I believe I need to register this:

```
private static void RegisterDatabase(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MarkingManagerDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<MarkingManagerDbContext>(liveoptions => liveoptions.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("MarkingManagerLIVEConnection")));

        }
```

This is what is on the console apps `Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Register Services");
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            RegisterServices.Register(services);
            Console.WriteLine("=>Done");

            _services = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            Console.Write("DB Configuration");
            var context = _services.GetRequiredService<MarkingManagerDbContext>();
            var mmSeed = _services.GetRequiredService<MarkingManagerSeed>();

            if (context.Database.EnsureCreated())
            {
                context.Database.Migrate();

                var mmSeedTesk = mmSeed.Seed();
                mmSeedTesk.Wait();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("=>Done");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the process");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

How do I make use of the "Live" Connectionstring ? Or am I missing something?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: research using multiple environments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Comment: I didnt read in detail, but based on what I read, this is to determine whether you want to use either a development or production environment ? I want to be able to connect to the Prod DB, grab data and insert into my test DB.

Comment: Why? I get that you would want a second connection for application testing but 1. not simultaneously to your live connection and 2.you really don't need to transfer the data from one DB to another through you application. Try to transfer the data on your DBs and comment one connection out respectively depending on wheather you roll out or test your application.